# Comparing contents of two csv in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

I want to compare contents of two csv files using unix.The Rules of this comparison are compare the Application name of the two files if it matches compare the file_number and return success or failure message based on the comparison.ie if both the file_number matches.

First file is:

file_number Application_name

```
25,AWX
78,UYH
90,TGY
89,GHB
```

Second file is:

file_number Application_name Date message

```
92, AWX, 2014-12-01 , SUCCESS 
66, AWX, 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS 
3, UYH, 2014-12-01 , SUCCESS 
3, TGY, 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS 
90, TGY , 2014-12-01 , SUCCESS 
89, GHB , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
```

My final output should be like this:

```
AWX , FAIL
UYH, FAIL
TGY, SUCCESS
GHB, SUCCESS
```

Any help?

Comment: I can't figure out how you're trying to compare them. Rather than giving an example, can you explain what the rules are for this comparison?

Comment: Your question is too vague. 

To give more insight into what you are after: give column names for both CSV tables, and define what your success and fail criteria are.

Comment: What is your Success/Fail criteria? Is it if File numbers don't change it is a Success else Fail?

Comment: yes if filenumbers are same it is a success else failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to order your files.

```
sort input1.txt > filename1.txt
sort input2.txt | cut -f1,2,4 -d, > filename2.txt
```

In the second file, I removed the date, because is not necessary in the output.

```
$ join -a1 -j1 -t, filename1.txt filename2.txt | cut -f2,4 -d, | sort > intermediate1.txt
```

Join the files, keeping unpairable lines from file 1 `-a1`. The results concatenate fields from both files, so we only want fields 2 and 4 (`cut`) and then sort the output.

```
$ cat intermediate1.txt
AWX
GHB, SUCCESS
TGY, SUCCESS
UYH

$ cat intermediate1.txt | awk '!/SUCCESS/{print $1", FAIL"}' > intermediate2.txt
```

Add the string `, FAIL` to the lines that does not contain `SUCCESS`.

```
$ join -a1 -t, intermediate1.txt intermediate2.txt > final.txt
```

Join again and you have it.

```
$ cat final.txt 
AWX, FAIL
GHB, SUCCESS
TGY, SUCCESS
UYH, FAIL
```